# SQL datasource /datagrid from code behind

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I am trying to extract the username from the authentication cookie and use it to send a request to the database to pull in the the information for that particular user using a datagrid or sql data source.

I know how to implement a sql datasource /datagrid in the front end (asp.net) but I am confused about how to do it in the code behind so that I can utilize the value of the username there

The code I am using to pull in the username is

```
        IPrincipal p = HttpContext.Current.User;

        string userid = p.Identity.Name;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

** This is what you put in the code behind 
datagrid1.datasource = MethodToGetTheDataSourceFromTheDatabase(p.Identity.Name);
datagrid1.databindI();
**

Then you would just have MethodToGetTheDataSourceFromTheDatabase execute the sql statement that you want executed and return the datatype(dataset, dataadapter, List<>, etc...)

Comment: Thanks @DavidEdwards ,but I am not exactly sure I follow .Can you please elaborate with an example (sorry but I am really new to asp.net and the entity framework)